# How do I search trough query results, to prevent making to many requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the below set of queries, but I'm sure this isn't DRY. However, I can't find out how to filter trough the deals var instead of querying again for each var. Is it possible?

```
deals = Deal.all
won = Deal.find( :all, :conditions => ["status = 'won'"] ).count
pending = Deal.find( :all, :conditions => ["status = 'pending'"] ).count
lost = Deal.find( :all, :conditions => ["status = 'lost'"] ).count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) SQL clause:

```
Hash[Deal.all(:select => 'status, count(*) as count', :group => 'status').map{|e| 
  [e.status, e.count]
}]
```

Edit: I forgot that you already have all the records loaded. In that case, you can get counts per status this way:

```
Hash[deals.group_by(&:status).map{|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
```

Comment: This one is beautiful! Only thing I can come up with for possible improvement is if it could use the already defined var deals, would't that make it even better? (Nice conceptual thinking here too, good to see this kind of solutions:-))

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:-

Deal.find(:all, :select => 'status, count(id) as deal_count', :group => 'status')

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000331):

```
deals = Deal.all
won   = deals.select { |deal| deal.status == 'won' }.length
# similar for pending and lost
```

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I was looking for. Although Mladen Jablanović' answer is more flexible it takes an extra db call during which it has to do more I/O than this solution. As long as you know what deal statuses there are this is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Ruby's inject function for this:

```
won = deals.inject(0) {|total, deal| deal.status == 'won' ? total + 1 : total }
```

Comment: I thought about this kind of solution, but I think this isn't a good idea, basically this redefines count().

Comment: Good point. Letting the database handle the count, is probably much more efficient anyway.

Comment: I believe he was referring to `Array#count`: `deals.count{|deal| deal.status == 'won'}`.

Answer (score 0):

if your Deal objects are ActiveRecord objects (which is typically the case for models), you can launch the count on the data base:

`won = Deal.count_by_sql("select count(*) from deals where status = 'won'")`

Another way to do it would be to write the sql query that would do the all the count for you, and group them by status:

`count_by_status = Deal.find_by_sql("select status,count(*) from deals group by status;")`

Then you can use the result (which will be an array of hashes I think).